# Keycloak admin service account tab missing

Tags: keycloak, service-accounts

I am trying to reach Keycloak Service Account settings. I have a Keycloak version 18.0.2. There is a `confidential` Access Type for the client. `Service Accounts Enabled` option is switched on. Also, I have a Keycloak admin user on a `Master` realm with Assigned Roles `manage-clients` `manage-realm` `manage-users` for realm-management. Here's how it looks:

[image: Service Account User field is absent]

[image: Client Roles]

Although, I can authorize using SA and get it via Keycloak API, I cannot access it using the admin UI. I want to obtain the result below, where `Service Account User` editing opportunity is available. Appreciate any help!

[image: Service Account User field]